# Typedef redefinition error when running Unity iOS project in Xcode 9 simulator

Tags: unity, ios

I was able to run my Unity 2017.1.0b10 iOS project successfully on my iPhone 6S+ (Using Xcode 9). I changed the `Target SDK` to `Simulator SDK` to try it out on other device simulators then I got the following errors in the `UnityMetalSupport.h` file.

[image]

Below are screenshots of my player settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would really appreciate some help here

Comment: I also have same problem in Xcode 9 but i m using unity 5.6 and working on VR game.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. It looks like simply deleting/commenting out those offending lines works.

```
//typedef NSUInteger MTLPixelFormat;
//enum
//{
//    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm,
//    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB,
//};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your build device, change any simulator to "Generic iOS Device".
The ENUM produced these errors are already defined in iOS simulators.